# Why did 'Let it out' change so much from Urban Shadows 1e to 2e?

Tags: edition-comparison, designer-reasons, urban-shadows, urban-shadows-2e

In my Urban Shadows 2e quickstart the basic move 'Let it out' reads:

> ### LET IT OUT
>
> When you let out the power within you, choose an ability from your playbook and roll with Spirit. On a hit, mark corruption and activate the ability; the MC will tell you
> how the effect is costly, limited, or unstable. On a 10+, ignore the corruption or the complications, your choice.

But in the first edition it read:

> When you let out the power within you, roll with Spirit. On a hit, choose 1 and mark corruption. On a 10+, ignore the corruption or choose another from the list.
>
> • Take +1 forward on your next roll
>
> • Extend your senses, supernatural or otherwise
>
> • Frighten, intimidate, or impress your opposition
>
> • Take definite hold of something vulnerable or expose

Have the designers ever explained why they made that change?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The designers of Urban Shadows 2e have a [blog post](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/magpiegames/urban-shadows-second-edition/posts/3592068) explaining their decision to change the move from first edition:

> [Let it out] is a great all-purpose move, one that balanced the chance for corruption against a broad array of powers and abilities.
>
> But… it also **required a good degree of mental gymnastics** on the part of the players. [...] when you let it out (in 1E), you have to **hold both the trigger and the options in mind**, authoring your abilities in the fiction without any guidance!

So they wanted to encourage the use of the ability by streamlining it:

> The new version of let it out **gives up that flexibility for a set of specific abilities**,

Making things easier on the player,

> If one of [the specific abilities] seems helpful, then the **roll is really about determining the efficacy** (full or partial) and **the cost** (corruption or no corruption).

But they admit:

> The playbook abilities do limit things a bit

---

That's the reason behind why it changed — streamlining the move, and focusing on the how successful the move is and the cost (which is corruption, a core mechanic of the game).